# Python curses is segfaulting on window refresh

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I'm writing an application that uses Python's curses library, but calling `window.addch(...)` followed by `window.refresh()` seems to arbitrarily cause segfaults. I've narrowed the offending code to the following snippet:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
  window = curses.newwin(5, 5, 5, 0)
  window.addch(0, 0, 'A')
  window.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Running this seems to segfault about 50% of the time, while the other 50% it runs perfectly fine, without anything obvious about when it segfaults or executes correctly.

I'm running on Arch Linux with `ncurses-6.0-4` and `python-3.5.2-1`. It crashes with or without `tmux-2.3-1` in both `zsh-5.2-1` and `bash-4.3.046-1`

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: I'd use valgrind to investigate this (in a quick check, it reports lots of uninitialized problems with **python** but not much with the actual ncurses calls).